# Reading JSON Web API 2 InvalidModelStateResult result using AFNetworking

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, afnetworking, asp.net-web-api2, afnetworking-2

I am trying to handle ModelState issues in an iOS application I'm building. When I want to sign up the user I send their details to the following method:

```
    // POST api/Account/Register
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("Register")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(RegisterBindingModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };

        IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            return GetErrorResult(result);
        }

        return Ok();
    }
```

I read the JSON response with the following method in my iOS application (Swift):

```
func register(user:RegisterModel, successClosure: (() -> ())?, failureClosure: (() -> ())?) {
    let manager  = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()
    let registerUrl = XXXX

    manager.POST( registerUrl,
        parameters: ["email": user.email, "password": user.password, "confirmpassword": user.passwordConfirmation],
        success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,responseObject: AnyObject!) in
            println("register success")
            if let succ = successClosure {
                succ()
            }
        },
        failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,error: NSError!) in
            println("register fail")
            println(error)
            if let fail = failureClosure {
                fail()
            }
    })
}
```

When I receive an error (`BadRequest(ModelState)`), I get output like the following:

```
Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: bad request (400)" UserInfo=0x7f8663e3e890 {com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7f8663e3cba0> { URL: http://192.168.0.71:8888/api/Account/Register } { status code: 400, headers {
"Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
"Content-Length" = 227;
"Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
Date = "Sun, 17 Aug 2014 00:31:57 GMT";
Expires = "-1";
Pragma = "no-cache";
Server = "Microsoft-IIS/8.0";
"X-AspNet-Version" = "4.0.30319";
"X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
"X-SourceFiles" = "=?UTF-8?B?WjpcUHJvamVjdHNcTGFybnNmaXRcTGFybnNmaXRcYXBpXEFjY291bnRcUmVnaXN0ZXI=?=";
} }, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: bad request (400), NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://192.168.0.71:8888/api/Account/Register}
```

Is Web API 2 not sending me the reason for the ModelState not being valid? Or am I accessing the error response incorrectly? Ultimately, I want to know what the reason is for the ModelState not being valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In AFNetworking, the error provided by Web API 2 can be accessed via `operation.responseString`